# xml Transformation can't resolve namespace definition

Tags: xslt, transform, xerces, xalan

My code is something like:

```
public static void transform(InputStream in, Source xslt, OutputStream out) throws TransformerException {

    //com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl
    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer t = tFactory.newTransformer(xslt);

    Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(in);

    Result outResult = new StreamResult(out);

    t.transform(xmlSource, outResult);

}
```

And when I try to transform my xml:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException
ERROR:  'Cannot compile stylesheet'
CRITICAL ERROR:  'java.net.MalformedURLException'
       :null

javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: java.net.MalformedURLException
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(Unknown Source)
at it.unimaticaspa.digipark.utils.XmlUtils.transform(XmlUtils.java:42)
at it.unimaticaspa.digipark.utils.XmlUtilsTest.testTransform(XmlUtilsTest.java:85)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(Unknown Source)
... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
... 41 more
```

at the line:

```
tFactory.newTransformer(xslt);
```

I think it's about the fact that both xml and xslt declare namespaces that didn't point to an existing xsd, so i thought to disable the validation of the schema, and i saw the function setAttribute and setFeature, but i can't find any working example, or a list of attributes/features available.
Debugging the code i found that the implementation class of the xml transformer is:
com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl

-- edit --

As suggested I post my files also:

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test:Root xmlns:test="http://www.mysite.it/test/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mysite.it/test/xsdTest.xsd">
<test:Branch>
    <test:Leaf>someValue1</test:Leaf>
</test:Branch>
<test:Branch>
    <test:Leaf>someValue2</test:Leaf>
    <test:Leaf>someValue3</test:Leaf>
</test:Branch>
<test:Branch>
    <test:Sub-Branch>
        <test:Leaf>someValue4</test:Leaf>
    </test:Sub-Branch>
    <test:Leaf>someValue5</test:Leaf>
</test:Branch>
</test:Root>
```

xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0"
    xmlns:test="http://www.mysite.it/test/"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.unimaticaspa.it/test/xsdTest.xsd">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="test:Root">
    <sincro:IdC xmlns:sincro="http://www.uni.com/U3011/sincro/"
        xmlns:somenamespace="http://www.mysite.it/mysite-metadata/"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.uni.com/U3011sincro/IdC.xsd http://www.mysite.it/mysite-metadata/Metadata.xsd"
        sincro:url="http://www.uni.com/U3011/sincro/"
        sincro:version="1.0">


        <sincro:VdC>
            <sincro:ID sincro:scheme="local">asd</sincro:ID>
        </sincro:VdC>

        <xsl:for-each select="test:Branch">
            <sincro:FileGroup>
                <sincro:File sincro:encoding="BASE64" sincro:format="TXT">
                    <sincro:ID>asd</sincro:ID>
                    <sincro:MoreInfo sincro:XMLScheme="http://www.mysite.it/mysite-metadata/Metadata.xsd">
                        <sincro:EmbeddedMetadata>
                            <somenamespace:Metadata>
                                <somenamespace:mytag>asd</somenamespace:mytag>
                            </somenamespace:Metadata>
                        </sincro:EmbeddedMetadata>
                    </sincro:MoreInfo>
                </sincro:File>
            </sincro:FileGroup>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </sincro:IdC>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

-- EDIT --

added missing declaration: xsi:schemaLocation on tag xsl:stylesheet.
Still doesn't work, it keep giving the same error.

I tried to run my xslt with XMLSpy and it worked fine, i really think that the problem is on the TransformerFactory Configuration.

Comment: can you show snippets of input XML and XSLT code?

Comment: How do you create the `Source` that is passed as the `xslt` parameter to this method?  I can't see anything wrong with the XSLT itself, but if this `Source` is not configured correctly then it could produce the kind of error you're seeing.

Comment: you're right, i've finally found the error: I was creating a Source from a null InputStream from a file that didn't existed, the error message put me on the wrong way... what a waste of time for such a trivial error...

Comment: I don't know how to close the post.. can I reply to my own question and sign it as the right answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because the XSLT Source (system id) is defined by an URL earlier in the code. This URL is malformed (or null maybe, hence null pointer exception in the stacktrace).

Comment: Your response was the closest to the solution: the object Source that I was passing were binded not to an URL, but to an InputStream pointingto a non existent file (I had mispelled the filename), causing the MalformedURLException.

Answer (score 0):

XML Namespace names don't have to point to XSDs, or indeed point to anything. They *do* have to be syntactically correct URIs, and if they're URLs they have to be absolute URLs rather than relative. You haven't shown us your stylesheet, but that's the first thing to look at fixing.

EDITED TO ADD:

Looking at what you've shown us (in the comments on this answer), one error jumps out immediately:

```
xmlns:test="mysite.it/test/";
```

Wrong. Namespace names must be absolute URIs, not relative. Change it to

```
xmlns:test="http://mysite.it/test/";
```

Also, the semicolons don't belong there. Remove them, and review proper XML syntax.

Comment: that's my xml:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <test:Root xmlns:test="http://www.mysite.it/test/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mysite.it/test/xsdTest.xsd" >
 <test:Branch>
  <test:Leaf>someValue1</test:Leaf>
 </test:Branch>
 <test:Branch>
  <test:Leaf>someValue2</test:Leaf>
  <test:Leaf>someValue3</test:Leaf>
 </test:Branch>
 <test:Branch>
  <test:Sub-Branch>
   <test:Leaf>someValue4</test:Leaf>
  </test:Sub-Branch>
  <test:Leaf>someValue5</test:Leaf>
 </test:Branch>
    </test:Root>

Comment: and the xsl:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xmlns:test="http://www.mysite.it/test/" >
 <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="test:Root">

Comment: <sincro:IdC xmlns:sincro="http://www.uni.com/U3011/sincro/"
   xmlns:somenamespace="http://www.mysite.it/mysite-metadata/"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.uni.com/U3011sincro/IdC.xsd http://www.mysite.it/mysite-metadata/Metadata.xsd"
   sincro:url="http://www.uni.com/U3011/sincro/"
   sincro:version="1.0">
<sincro:VdC>
    <sincro:ID sincro:scheme="local">asd</sincro:ID>
   </sincro:VdC>

Comment: <xsl:for-each select="test:Branch">
    <sincro:FileGroup>
     <sincro:File sincro:encoding="BASE64" sincro:format="TXT">
      <sincro:ID>asd</sincro:ID>
      <sincro:MoreInfo sincro:XMLScheme="http://www.mysite.it/mysite-metadata/Metadata.xsd">
       <sincro:EmbeddedMetadata>
        <somenamespace:Metadata>
         <somenamespace:mytag>asd</somenamespace:mytag>
        </somenamespace:Metadata>
       </sincro:EmbeddedMetadata>
      </sincro:MoreInfo>
     </sincro:File>
    </sincro:FileGroup>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </sincro:IdC>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Might have been more readable to edit those into the original question, so you didn't have to break them up.

Comment: I posted the files. About the URI: in the original file there were also the http://www, I dont know why posting it in the comment made it disappeared..

Comment: Turns out that there's a feature (misfeature?) in this system which mangles URIs in text -- and comments are considered text. To bypass that, enclose the URI in backquotes to mark it as code, like so: `http://mysite.it`.

Comment: Ok, but now that i've posted the correct files, have you some hints on where are the cause of the problem?

Comment: The exception says it's happening while loading the stylesheet, so the problem is in either loading or processing the stylesheet. 

As you concluded above, the problem turned out to be the URI that specified where you were loading the stylesheet. So my answer was not relevant to your particular problem.